# Inject any html/ component inside a component using angular 4+

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I have a popup component and I want to inject any custom component to that.
Currently I'm using [innerHTML], but it's not able to render any custom component. I read this https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader, but not able to implement using this. So please suggest.

### **popup.component.ts**

```
<p-dialog [(visible)]="display" [responsive]="true" [blockScroll]=true (onHide)="onHide($event)" [width]="width" [resizable]="false">
    <p-header>
        <i>{{ title }}</i>
    </p-header>
    <div [innerHtml]="content|sanitizehtml"></div>
    <p-footer>
        <button type="button" pButton icon="pi pi-close" (click)="buttonClick($event)" [label]="noLabel" class="ui-button-secondary"></button>
        <button type="button" pButton icon="pi pi-check" (click)="buttonClick($event)" [label]="yesLabel"></button>
    </p-footer>
  </p-dialog>
```

**app.componet.ts**

```
    openLookup(e){
        this.display = true;
        this.title = 'Product ID';

        this.content = `<p-checkbox [(ngModel)]="someFlag" binary="true" (onChange)="changedRow()"></p-checkbox>
<p-calendar  name="endDate" [(ngModel)]="endDate" [monthNavigator]="true" [yearNavigator]="true" yearRange="1990:3000" [disabledDays]="[0,6]" [showIcon]="true" styleClass="full-width" inputStyleClass="calender-width">

                                    </p-calendar>`;

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to maintain popup html content as child component

You can also use  with select attribute

Parent Component:

```
<child-component>
    <div sample>Parent Content</div>
</child-component>
```

Child Component:

```
...
<ng-content select="[sample]"></ng-content>
...
```

Output:

```
...
<div>Parent Content</div>
...
```

Also you could try using ng-container

Comment: Thanks @Mebin Joe. But, I want to inject html from any parent component. I think your solution's isn't what I'm looking for :)